# I need to add an option "where" to my sql request

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to added option `where` to "party" selection.

This is my working code:

```
SELECT p.id, (
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM accounts
WHERE party = p.id
) AS u_count, p.title, p.slogan, p.owner, u.nickname, p.candidat, c.nickname, p.register_date
FROM party p
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts u ON p.owner = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts c ON p.candidat = c.id
```

This case is not working: (with **WHERE confirmed = 1**)

```
SELECT p.id, (
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM accounts
WHERE party = p.id
) AS u_count, p.title, p.slogan, p.owner, u.nickname, p.candidat, c.nickname, p.register_date
FROM party p WHERE confirmed = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts u ON p.owner = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts c ON p.candidat = c.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax must be `select ... from .. join ... on ... where ...`

```
SELECT p.id, (
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM accounts
WHERE party = p.id
) AS u_count, p.title, p.slogan, p.owner, u.nickname, p.candidat, c.nickname, p.register_date
FROM party p LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts u ON p.owner = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts c ON p.candidat = c.id
WHERE confirmed = 1
```